# Am trying to add IAM Roles in EC2 Server - RDS still accessible even after add Effect Deny

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, rds

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "rds:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

S3 is working fine. If i change Effect to allow i can able to access/view files, same way if i changed to Deny am not able to visible. The same way i want to allow to users only required service from AWS. For Testing Am complete blocking RDS Service but its not happening.

Comment: S3 i make it Allow and Deny, It showing images vice versa.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking. Could you please Edit your question and describe what you are trying to achieve and what problem you are experiencing? Thank you.

Comment: @John Rotenstein Can you look at once my problem.

Comment: You're trying to prevent this instance from *connecting* to an RDS instance using an IAM instance role policy?

Comment: Ranganath, your question is still not clear. Please Edit your question and describe your environment (what do you have? EC2? RDS?), what you would like to achieve (what do you want to connect to what?), and what difficulty you are experiencing. If you change something, show us what you changed it to. If there is an error message, show us your error message. If you are saying that you wish to block the EC2 instance from communicating with the RDS instance, show us your Security Groups (*not* your IAM configuration).